# How to add both time window constraint and capacity constraint to VRP?

Tags: python, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I have just started working on VRPs with Google's OR Tools. I would like to impose multiple constraints on my VRP i.e. instead of just adding just one among time window constraint or capacity constraint, I would like to have both the constraints to solve my problem without taking into account the cost. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

everything is shown here, multiple examples, one per feature, in C++/Python/Java/C#.

https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/ortools/constraint_solver/doc/VRP.md

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. I would also like to sort out one more thing. Instead of multiple vehicles making up to different nodes and picking up loads, I want a single vehicle to have multiple trips to achieve this. Any inputs on the same?

Comment: look at https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/ortools/constraint_solver/samples/cvrp_reload.py basically you need to duplicate the depot and use a negative capacity demand to simulate an *unload*

Comment: This link doesn't work anymore. Why @laurent ?